# Modify All In One SEO pack generated meta tags

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I am using **All In One SEO pack (AIOSp)**, everything is good,
but I have one article (Page) where users can comment, there are several pages with user comments. 
Each comment page has different URL (/about/guestbook/comment-page-18/#comments) and I want to have different metas on them (" - Page 2"...)

Question is - **is there any way to modify title, description, keywords generated by AIOSp to add " - page 2", " - page 3" etc.**

I can modify core classes of AIOSp but all changes will be erased by next update, adding changes after each update not a good solution for me.

there is 
`do_action( 'aioseop_modules_wp_head' );`
but it is after `echo`ing meta tags

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunaetly, I did not find any other solution than **modify core classes of AIOSp and keep a backup in case plugin will be updated** =(